# How to give value to a typedef alias pointer through function?

Tags: c

I want to create a new `championship` in a function but whenever i give value to it the code builds but when running it stops at this part.

```
typedef struct
{
    char id[10];
    int c;
}team;

typedef struct
{
    team t1;
    team t2;
    int t1g;
    int t2g;
}match;

typedef struct
{
  match matches[30];
  team teams[6];
  int teamno;
  int played;
}* championship;

championship newchampionship(){
    championship temp;
    temp->played=0;
    temp->teamno=0;
    return temp;
}

int main(){
   championship ch1=newchampionship();
   ...
}
```

Whenever it gets to `temp->played=0;` the whole thing stops and the process returns with -1073741819.

Any idea how to fix this? I just want a championship with empty arrays and 0 in the int's.

Comment: `temp` is a pointer, but *where does it point?*

Comment: Also, please don't create type-aliases of pointers. It usually makes code harder to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: As said, don't do pointer aliases. Use `championship * temp = malloc(..)`. Your problem is that you declare a pointer but you don't allocate memory for it.

Comment: You should always enable compiler warnings. The compiler should warn you when you use a variable that is not initialized.

Comment: As @Gerhardh mentioned, make sure to compile your code with the necessary flags `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`

Answer (score -1):

Change your code as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
  match matches[30];
  team teams[6];
  int teamno;
  int played;
} championship;

championship *newchampionship(){
    championship *temp = malloc(sizeof championship);
    temp->played=0;
    temp->teamno=0;
    return temp;
}

int main(){
   championship *ch1=newchampionship();
   ...
}
```

Comment: `T *p = malloc(sizeof *p)` is a much more robust idiom than `T *p = malloc(sizeof (T))` because there is no chance of the sizeof (T) failing to match up with the T that was used to declare p. It's also more concise and easier to read. In this case it would be `malloc(sizeof *temp)`

Comment: When sizeof's operand is a type, it has to be enclosed in parentheses. But when sizeof's operand is a variable, this is not required. In your current case it has to be enclosed in parantheses.